# How to exchange Google auth details for AWS Cognito user pool keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, cordova, amazon-cognito

After authenticating with Google, following [the guide here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#login), I end up with this set:

```
 email          // 'eddyverbruggen@gmail.com'
 userId         // user id
 displayName    // 'Eddy Verbruggen'
 familyName     // 'Verbruggen'
 givenName      // 'Eddy'
 imageUrl       // 'http://link-to-my-profilepic.google.com'
 idToken        // idToken that can be exchanged to verify user identity.
 serverAuthCode // Auth code that can be exchanged for an access token and refresh token for offline access
 accessToken    // OAuth2 access token
```

How do I use these to get back a Cognito user pool session consisting of:

```
 "access_token":"eyJz9sdfsdfsdfsd" 
 "refresh_token":"dn43ud8uj32nk2je"
 "id_token":"dmcxd329ujdmkemkd349r"
```

---

Turns out, this is [not supported yet](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/542#issuecomment-400470753). Here's a [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/1126).

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you need to [enable a Federated Identity in AWS Cognito Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/google.html#set-up-google-1.javascript). That document provides this snippet, which shows that you need to use the `idToken` in the response from Google:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {

    // Add the Google access token to the Cognito credentials login map.
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
      Logins: {
        'accounts.google.com': authResult['id_token']
      }
    });

    // Obtain AWS credentials
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
      // Access AWS resources here.
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah.. close, but that would just authenticate the user within the identity pools. I need to do this for the user pools.

Comment: Here's the unfortunate [verdict for now](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/issues/542#issuecomment-400467201)

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the update. Hope to try something similar soon so will keep an eye on this or update if I find an alternate path.